# Windows Updates: How to automatically install Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool (without user intervention)?

Tags: windows, windows-update

Every so often Windows Update pushes out an updated version of this tool. Unfortunately, each time the user has to agree to the EULA.

**Is there any way of configuring the Windows Update service to simply accept this automatically?**

(I'm not worried about the EULA content).

Comment: Doesn't the automatic install take care of this? Though the EULA question is there for a reason ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, the automatic install doesn't take care of this. The updates are queued up, but the EULA acceptance blocks the auto install. I'm looking for a way around this without using WSUS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I've been unable find a way of automatically accepting the EULA (short of using WSUS).

I then considered how to fool Windows into thinking the latest version of the Malicious Software Removal Tool (MRT) is already installed. I discovered this can be done by tweaking the MRT's Version key in the registry, so that it has the latest month's GUID.

I got the latest month's GUID from the following Microsoft page (Q2 under the FAQ heading):

> [Deployment of the Microsoft Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool in an enterprise environment](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=891716#13)

I updated the registry for this month (March 2010) and now Windows won't nag until next month when I can repeat this process again:

> `reg add \HKLM\Software\Microsoft\RemovalTools\MRT\ /v Version /t REG_SZ /d 076DF31D-E151-4CC3-8E0A-7A21E35CF679`

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Ivo this prompt will only appear when doing a manual Windows Update. Automatic updates pushed via WSUS or Windows Updates set to automatically install will not prompt the user for this.

If you using WSUS when approving the update you will be prompted for the EULA once as administrator and it will be accepted for all machines on the WSUS server.

Comment: If using WSUS - yes, but straightforward automatic updates - always need EULA acceptance by the user - unless there is some setting I'm missing?

Comment: @Umber. It only requires the acceptance when the updates are not installed automatically. If set to only download it will always prompt.

Comment: Even when updates are set to download and install automatically, the MSRT will not install automatically - the EULA always holds it up.

Comment: @Umber That's very strange. I have it set-up like this at home and have never seen the prompt for the MSRT unless I do a manual update.